# Why does the correlation between decision trees have to be positive?

Tags: correlation, variance

In the book "Elements of statistical learning" we have that the variance of a the random forest is given by

$V(\frac{1}{n} \sum X_i)= \rho \sigma^2+ \frac{1-\rho}{n}\sigma^2$

where $\rho$ is the pairwise correlation between all $n$ trees which all have variance $\sigma^2$.
It is stated that $\rho\geq 0$ otherwise the proof fails. I know that $\rho\geq -1/(n-1)$ but that does not imply that $\rho>0$? Say we have $n=3$ we have that $\rho$ can take the values $-0.5$ without violating anything. How come the proof is only for $\rho\geq 0$?

Comment: Try substituting any negative number (well, between $-1$ and $0$) for $\rho$, and see what happens to the sign of the variance as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: In the limit I do see the problem, but In general that is not a problem. That is where I see the struggle

Comment: It's not in the limit.  Regardless of what $\rho < 0$ you choose, there is a finite $n$ for which the variance is negative, and remains negative for all greater $n$.  This means the proof fails.  It's not a proof if it only works for certain combinations of $\rho$ and $n$ and fails for all the rest.  Note also that for any given $\rho$, the number of $n$s for which the proof fails is countably infinitely greater than the (finite) number for which it works.

Comment: True that! Thanks

Comment: Feel free to add it as an answer

Comment: Thanks!  Will do, after work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof doesn't hold for $\rho < 0$, as for any $\rho < 0$, there exists an $n_0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$, $\rho + \frac{1-\rho}{n} < 0$, and therefore the calculated variance $V(\frac{1}{n} \sum X_i)$ will be less than $0$ as well.

We can easily find $n_0$, as it is the smallest integer greater than or equal to $-(1-\rho)/\rho$.